# What is the classpath of message.properties if in dependency jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I made several dependency jar files by Spring, and some of the classes requires Spring messageSource to load i18n  external translation.

So in maven I create following resources to for packing the jar file

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF/i18n/</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

just copy those i18n files into `%JAR_FILE%/WEB-INF/i18n/` so I hope Spring application can load the these language file, but failed(complaining about `No message found under code "THE_PROPERTY"`). Then question is, can spring scan and load all classpaths under dependencies in `WEB-INF\lib` and include all those `.properties` files, if specified in Spring-config.xml?

If so, then what should be the correct class path for the file in the jar?

Comment: What did you end up doing ?

Answer (score 1):

Use classpath in MessageSource config:

```
"classpath:/WEB-INF/i18n/messages/common"
```

Of course, the files would need to be in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, that even works when the properties files are in the dependency jar?

Answer (score 0):

To works also in dependency jar you have to put all properties file in /src/main/resources/ in each project and then define the ResourceBundleMessageSource in the following way:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>file1</value>
            <value>file2</value>
            <value>file3</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This definition will look up in each jar classpath